# Changing header size on blog posts only

Tags: css, wordpress

I would like to change the size of header text on all my blog posts but keep the header size on all other pages.

I have tried the following

```
.entry-title a {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

But it has no effect.

Would anybody know how to achieve this?

thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

To set css for ONLY single blog posts, you can use this:

```
.single-post .entry-title a {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

If you use posts other places, the css will also be used there.

Comment: thanks so much for this. Very much appreciated. I have tried this and it has no effect. I've cleared the cache to no avail. Any ideas why this doesn't work?